# Java: How to compare number of spaces in between words when space is used as delimiter

Tags: java

I have a file that is space delimited. I am looking for a way to find if the number of spaces between words are same or different. For example, assume :

- number of spaces between word#1 and word#2 is 3
- number of spaces between word#2 and word#3 is 4

What I have tried is :

```
long spaces = line.chars().filter(c -> c == (int)' ').count();
long isDelimiter = (spaces % (columns-1)));
```

And if isDelimiter == 0 then equal or unequal.

Is there a better way to find that out?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What code you have tried? What errors you get? You have to provide details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no research effort was shown.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many ways to do this, but one way is to use String.split(" ");

If there are 2 words with one space in between them, the resulting array will be {"word1", "word2}.  If there are 2 words with two spaces in between them, the result would be {"word1", "", word2"}.  If there are 3 spaces between words, the array would be {"word1", "", "", "word2"}.

In your example, the array would look like: {"word#1", "", "", "word#2", "", "", "", "word#3"}

So just loop through the resulting array from split(" "), and if the String is an empty String it counts as an extra space between words.